# Replace ceiling light

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a light fixture with a new  bulb socket fixture, Coming out of the junction box in the ceiling are four (4) wires. three (3) white and one red. Don't see any ground. How would I wire the new socket having only the normal three (3) wire configuration? (grnd, neutral and feed)?
Thank You.
Don deB.

Comment: Pictures? Any idea how the old fixture was connected?

Comment: Yes, can you post pictures of the inside of the junction box please?

Comment: Please [edit] your post, click the "sun & mountain" icon, then browse your computer to find your pictures. They will be uploaded to SE's hosting service and will display nicely in your question. Without good pics inside the box where the fixture is mounted, it will be hard to diagnose the issue from here. Once you've done that, and while you're waiting for an answer, take the [tour] and browse through the [help] so you can find out how to make the most of this site. One of the licensed electricians round here (like ThreePhaseEel) will be along to recommend a solution.